# how to save android project separately based on version on Android Studio?

Tags: android, backup, version

Is there any way to save android project separately based on project version?

I mean, for example, after i add to my project something and change version of project, how can i see old version?

Do i must to back up all project files for all versions or android studio has some trick to reach to old versions?

Seems sites like https://github.com/ does this work. But as i know, on github everybody can see our codes.Right?

Any suggestion about version control?

Thanks in advance.